# Legal to use non FCC-approved radio devices purchased locally?

Tags: emc, fcc

Does anyone know if it's legal to use non FCC-approved radio devices which are purchased **locally**? For instance, if the device is purchased from a local eBay seller, is it still legal to use it in any setting (commercial or otherwise)? AFAIK it is the importer's responsibility to ensure the device imported is compliant. So my take is that it is illegal to use unapproved devices bought from foreign sellers only. Is it correct?

EDIT: I'm referring to USA in particular.

Comment: It's about frequency and power rather than FCC approval. Apparently, if you use it commercially you will not be able to get any certification requiring FCC approval for the used equipment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not sure if I understand. By FCC approval I actually mean FCC compliance. For instance, can a business use cheap, uncertified, non-compliant Bluetooth tags purchased from a local eBay seller? Or more broadly, can uncertified radios purchased locally be used?

Comment: As I understand it, it is legal to use (as long as it is not interfering with something it should not interfere..), but illegal to import. Meaning that buying this thing is illegal (I assume we are speaking of US).

Comment: Isn't importing buying from a foreign seller only? If it was purchased from a local seller, would it still be "imported" by FCC's standards?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Doesn't the FCC's regulatory authority only permit it to regulate use? If a device isn't used for anything but a paperweight, for example, do they have any authority to regulate that paperweight or its sale?

Comment: @jonk Yeah, but the question here is who has the legal responsibility here - the vendor or the consumer.

Comment: Anyways, what if I am a developer developing a new RF device. Obviously it won't be FCC-certified at early stages, but some prototypes will be used for testing stages. Is it illegal?

Comment: @EugeneSh. AFAIK Non-compliant devices can be distributed in limited quantities for testing purposes. https://apps.fcc.gov/oetcf/kdb/forms/FTSSearchResultPage.cfm?switch=P&id=57012

Comment: @EugeneSh. There are FCC rules I remember reading decades ago (could be different now) that are/were specific to experimental devices and their use. There was substantial wiggle room for allowing HAM radio experts to create and test devices and ideas, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd imagine that the consumer is responsible for their operation. And any consumer who is operating "for profit" may have a higher legal threshold (my guess) in making sure devices they select do meet FCC operational rules. If the device falsifies information about itself and claims it has been tested and approved for specified uses by the FCC then I think that would be actionable in court and might serve protect the consumer. But the consumer would still have to cease the violating uses, too.

Comment: @jonk You mean that if someone is selling me some non-certified equipment, he has no responsibility as he can claim that he intended it to be used as a paperweight? I think one better consult a lawyer about their specific case....

Comment: @EugeneSh. If a seller is selling a product under false pretenses, then that's a separate legal problem and I believe they can be successfully sued. But if a seller is NOT selling it under false pretenses, then I'm suggesting it may be interpreted instead as an "experimental device" and the responsibility for operating that device within the FCC rules becomes the responsibility of the consumer of the product. I suspect this may require the consumer to have passed some licensing requirements, though.

Comment: @John: This will be country specific. You have no country in your question or in your user profile. Are we to assume USA?

Comment: @jonk But the FCC doesn't allow the sale of non-compliant experimental devices in the first place.

Comment: @Transistor Yes, USA.

Comment: @JohnM. Ah. That may be a very good point I missed recognizing. There will have to be written code on that topic. Should be able to be cited. But that sounds plausible to me. (I never tried to sell anything experimental and I'm not enough of a qualified HAM to know better.)

Comment: Anyhow, it looks like *someone* is committing a crime here, and the other one is an accomplice :)

Comment: @jonk Actually you CAN buy experimental devices, it was how the Angelia SDR board were imported from India. I cannot remember the appropriate form name now, but you basically fill out a declaration that the thing is for experimental use and that it will be used within the terms of your license and customs let it in. Hams have WIDE latitude to import random radio toys, only slight subtle point is that stuff the FCC did to try and clamp down on CB "Burners".

Comment: @jonk That's pretty neat, and makes sense - it's assumed anyone with a ham license knows what they're doing. Though that's assuming the buyer actually has a ham license.

Comment: @DanMills Thanks. I felt the reality is as you wrote -- that you can buy experimental devices. (I was almost certain of it.) But you've lent your understanding, as well, and that makes me feel as though my memory may not have failed me as much as it might have. So thanks. I think your answer and comments are a very close approximation to my understanding. So +1 now to your answer!

Comment: @immibis I have a ham license. But I know I don't know anywhere NEAR as much as someone with a class-A license knows about FCC rules. The technical side of licensing also got made A LOT EASIER some years back and I probably could, except for my poor knowledge of the FCC rules themselves, pass a class-A today. I'm pretty sure I still could NOT pass a class-A of days gone by, though. I know I'm *still* not that well-informed. They really lowered the standards some time back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you buy from a foreign seller then YOU are the importer, and so are responsible for any required certifications.

If you buy non approved product locally then you may be prosecuted for operation of an unlicesensed radio transmitter, in reality the usual result will be the man telling you to cease and desist from operating that equipment together with fines for the company that did the importing (But keep it up and the fines will start getting serious quickly).

And yea, HAM radio license holders have some strange and unique permissions, things like being allowed to build or modify transmitting sets and operate them without needing to get them certified. No other group of civilian radio users has that right.

Comment: I agree. The user is always responsible.  Of course there are exceptions for lab use.  ( but then I wouldn't be surprised if FCC's budget was cut)  nah they raised $114.6 billion in bandwidth auctions.

Answer (score 1):

No, the operator of the device is almost always responsible for compliance. If you are found to be non-compliant the FCC can issue fines and that's not something you want to deal with. It's really when the device is found to be non-compliant is when you should be worried, but there are many people (verizon has trucks that scan their bands and they can pinpoint non-compiant sources in their bands, if they do an that is you, then they'll turn you over to the FCC) that are interested in finding non-compliant people.

> RESPONSIBLE PARTIES The FCC has very specific rules as to who is
>   responsible for regulatory compliance regarding various types of RF
>   devices.
>
> Different rules apply for RF devices subject to various types of
>   authorization. The responsible party is the exclusive party that is
>   required to ensure that RF devices under its custody comply with FCC
>   rules. This includes all identical devices marketed after
>   authorization. Because the responsible party is liable for
>   noncompliant RF devices and related matters, that party will be
>   subject to FCC enforcement actions in the event potential rule
>   violations are discovered
>
> [(see 47 C.F.R. § 2.909)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/2.909).

Source: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7879929